# TextInputLayout.setError() throws an exception. Why and how to fix?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-textinputlayout

I am using support libary android-support-v7 Pkg.Revision=23.2.1. Compiled for API 23 and tested on 4.1.2 device. While trying to implement some modern UI patterns I have encountered this problem.

activity_test.xml layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextInputLayout EditText default - error" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClickButtonSetError"
        android:text="TextInputLayout.setError()" />

</LinearLayout>
```

ActivityTest.java

```
public class ActivityTest extends AppCompatActivity
{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    }


    public void onClickButtonSetError(View view) {
        TextInputLayout til = (TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.textInputLayout);
        til.setErrorEnabled(true);
        til.setError("This is a test error message.");
    }
}
```

If I try to set error on TextInputLayout via setError() method. This is BTW done through click on a button I get this exception:

```
10-06 15:47:55.239: E/AndroidRuntime(5780): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-06 15:47:55.239: E/AndroidRuntime(5780): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
10-06 15:47:55.239: E/AndroidRuntime(5780):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:275)
10-06 15:47:55.239: E/AndroidRuntime(5780):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4232)
10-06 15:47:55.239: E/AndroidRuntime(5780):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17298)
10-06 15:47:55.239: E/AndroidRuntime(5780):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
10-06 15:47:55.239: E/AndroidRuntime(5780):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-06 15:47:55.239: E/AndroidRuntime(5780):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-06 15:47:55.239: E/AndroidRuntime(5780):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
10-06 15:47:55.239: E/AndroidRuntime(5780):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-06 15:47:55.239: E/AndroidRuntime(5780):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-06 15:47:55.239: E/AndroidRuntime(5780):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
10-06 15:47:55.239: E/AndroidRuntime(5780):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
10-06 15:47:55.239: E/AndroidRuntime(5780):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-06 15:47:55.239: E/AndroidRuntime(5780): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-06 15:47:55.239: E/AndroidRuntime(5780):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-06 15:47:55.239: E/AndroidRuntime(5780):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-06 15:47:55.239: E/AndroidRuntime(5780):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:270)
10-06 15:47:55.239: E/AndroidRuntime(5780):     ... 11 more
10-06 15:47:55.239: E/AndroidRuntime(5780): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getPorterDuffColorFilter:()V from class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
10-06 15:47:55.239: E/AndroidRuntime(5780):     at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.updateEditTextBackground(TextInputLayout.java:700)
10-06 15:47:55.239: E/AndroidRuntime(5780):     at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.setError(TextInputLayout.java:592)
10-06 15:47:55.239: E/AndroidRuntime(5780):     at com.example.testandroidsupportv7.ActivityEditText.onClickButtonSetError(ActivityEditText.java:30)
10-06 15:47:55.239: E/AndroidRuntime(5780):     ... 14 more
```

As I can see the cause is IllegalAccessError which does tell me much. I guess the acces modififier for method getPorterDuffColorFilter() is not set correctly in library. But this is my guess. How can I get rid of this exception because this basiclay defeats the reason I migrated to app compat library?

Answer (score 1):

You are almost certainly using a different version of the class at runtime to the one you expect.

As per this

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getPorterDuffColorFilter:()V from class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
```

i found a workaround for you. below is the style that you have to apply in xml for textInputLayout.

```
<style name="TextLabel" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
<item name="android:textColorHint">@color/colorLightText</item>
<item name="android:textSize">14dp</item>
<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorMediumText</item>
<item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorAccent</item>
<item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/COLOR</item>
<item name="android:textColorLink">@color/COLOR</item>
```

Let me know if it is working for you or not.

Comment: No it doesnt. Same exception. Besides, I really cannot see how would changing colors solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bug, see: 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78377

It should be resolved by 24.0.0 .. try to update your android-support and check if that issue persists.

I strongly recommend to avoid using any workaround trick if there is a stable fundamental solution.

I hope that may help,'.

Comment: It is not the same exception. And app support 23.2.1 is the last version Icould find that works in our development environment. And support library is not available for download to test different versions.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem associated with onclick method ... , I don't know maybe you should try different , please change your layout and omit onclick attribute of Button and declare it in activity by full code like :

change button in activity_test.xml

```
   <Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnSetError"
    android:text="TextInputLayout.setError()" />
```

ActivityTest.java

```
public class ActivityTest extends AppCompatActivity
{
  private TextInputLayout txtInput; 
  private Button btnSetError;
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    txtInput = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputLayout);
    btnSetError =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSetError);
    btnSetError.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             txtInput.setError("ERROR");
        }
    });

}
```